# conditional render of navbar based on whether user is signed in on AWS amplify

Tags: authentication, vuejs3, navbar, aws-amplify, conditional-rendering

I am attempting to conditionally render a  and  based on whether or not a user is signed in or not using AWS amplify and Vue 3 for the frontend. I have been able to get it to not render and then render on sign in but when I log back out the navbar elements are still there and should have disappeared. I am new to Vue, so this maybe an easy fix but am unsure. I have tried making using both computed and a watch to try and force update the computed but that is not working. Any help would be much appreciated. The code is below:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <router-link @click="closeMenu" to="/" class="nav-branding"
        >Portal</router-link
      >
      <ul :class="[menuIsOpen ? 'active' : '', 'nav-menu']" v-show="isSignedIn">
        <li @click="toggleMenu" class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/pensions" class="nav-link">Pensions</router-link>
        </li>
        <li @click="toggleMenu" class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/benefits" class="nav-link">Benefits</router-link>
        </li>
        <li @click="toggleMenu" class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/annual-leave" class="nav-link"
            >Annual Leave</router-link
          >
        </li>
        <li @click="signOut" class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/" class="nav-link">Sign Out</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div
        @click="toggleMenu"
        :class="[menuIsOpen ? 'active' : '', 'hamburger']"
        v-show="isSignedIn"
      >
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div :class="[menuIsOpen ? 'pushed' : 'static']"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

export default {
  name: "NavBar",
  data() {
    return {
      menuIsOpen: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleMenu() {
      this.menuIsOpen = !this.menuIsOpen;
    },
    closeMenu() {
      this.menuIsOpen = false;
    },
    async signOut() {
      try {
        await Auth.signOut();
        // navigate to the login page or another route
        this.$router.push("/");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
    async isUser() {
      try {
        await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        return true;
      } catch {
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    isSignedIn() {
      return this.isUser();
    },
    watch: {
      isSignedIn() {
        this.$forceUpdate();
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
header {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #0d1520;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

.nav-branding {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #03e9f4;
}

.nav-branding:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.nav-link {
  transition: 0.7s ease;
  color: #03e9f4;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #03e9f4;
}

.hamburger:hover .bar {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4,
    0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .static {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    padding-top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #151f31;
  }

  .pushed {
    padding-top: 168px;
    transition: padding 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.2;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #151f31;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }

  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .nav-menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    gap: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #0d1520;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin: 16px 0;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the result from `isUser()`? Perhaps you should observe the value of `isUser()` especially when you sign out: `isSignedIn() { const user = this.isUser(); console.log(user); return user; }`. Please share your findings afterwards.

Comment: @ChristopherTabula it returns a promise, which I thought might be the problem, but not sure how to get around it as you can't do asynchronous in computed, as far as I understand. I am new to Vue so not entirely understanding how to get this to work

Comment: you should really be saving the result of the sign in information in some kind of `user` object.  the display of your navbar should then be conditional on `user` having some user data, i.e.`v-show="user"` is true when user is logged in and has data.  when logged out the `user` object should be set to null or undefined so that `v-show="user"` becomes false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

There're way too many "unknowns" in your problem thus it's difficult to give you a working answer. I'll give you hints but please read the Vue docs carefully to understand how to implement them and to also better understand the framework.

As you mentioned in the comments below, you're handling your sign in function in a "sibling" component and that both components are imported in the `App.vue`.

```bash
App.vue
views/
... NavBar.vue
... Login.vue
```

**Option #1**

Without the use of a state management, what you can do is move this code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return { isSignedIn: false };
  },
  methods: {
    async isAuthenticated() {
      try {
        await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

        this.isSignedIn = true;
      } catch {
        this.isSignedIn = false;
      }
    },
  }
  async mounted() {
    await this.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

in your App.vue, then use an [emitter](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events) in the login component so that your App.vue can "listen" whenever the user has logged in successfully. You can use `this.isAuthenticated()` as the callback function in the emit event prop. Then, pass the `this.isSignedIn` state as a [prop](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration) in your navbar component:

**Login.vue**

```js
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    signInUser() {
      /** your sign in logic */
      this.$emit('signIn')
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

**App.vue**

```html
<!-- Sample template -->
<NavBar :show="isSignedIn" />
<Login @sign-in="isAuthenticated" />
```

**Navbar.vue**

```js
export default {
  props: ['show'] // you can then pass show in your v-show
}
```

**Option #2**

You can also conditionally render the entire navbar component. However, you need to re-structure your templates a bit:

**App.vue**

```html
<Navbar v-show="isSignedIn"/>
```

**Option #3**

Ideally, App should not be responsible for managing the `isSignedIn` as the only components that use this state are the NavBar and Login components. With that said, consider using [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) to manage the states between components.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopherTabula, this has almost worked, however, I have to refresh the page before the change in visibility works. I.e, when I log in it does not render the elements until I refresh the page and if I log out the elements remain visible until the page is refreshed. How can I fix that part of the issue?

Comment: @Chris Where are you handling the sign in function? If its in a parent component, then you need to move the code there then pass `isSignedIn` as a prop to your navbar component. Then at the end of your sign in function, update the `isSignedIn`.

Comment: The sign in function is being handled in a sibling component. I am handling sign-in in a login component, that is rendered in the views folder. Both of which are rendered in the App.vue file

Comment: @Chris I've updated my answer. Please make sure to read the Vue docs carefully.

Comment: that's great thank you. Thank you for giving me a good variety of options. As you've said it might be best to use state management, will have to take a look at Pinia :)